# FactoryBot Realtionship: Association in Inherit factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

#### Description

I defined author, product and event factory.
and product can have author_id value or null.
and event can have product_id value or null.
I defined the association following but no works.
Can you give me an idea how to define the association?

```
factory :author do
    first_name FFaker::Name.first_name
    last_name FFaker::Name.last_name
end

factory :product do
    name Faker::Book.title
    factory :product_with_author do
        author
    end
end

factory :event do
name FFaker::Lorem.words
start_time Time.now-3.hours
end_time Time.now+1.hour
    
    factory :upcoming_event do
        is_active true
        product_with_author #I want a product with an author field, "undefined Method Error"
        # I also tried followings but not working, and I have no idea how to define this
        # product :product_with_author (Require Class but Symbol assigned error)
        # product product_with_author  (Implicit Conversion error)
    end

product 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the associations, but something like this should work. It creates an author for the product by defining the association and factory for it. As for the event, you can do that in a hook, `before(:create)` or `after(:create)` or `before(:build)` or `after(:build)`. As I stated in the snippet, I'm unaware of your associations, but you could pass the event to the product or vice versa in that block.

I find this [cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/factory_bot) very helpful in my factory bot issues

```rb
factory :author do
  first_name FFaker::Name.first_name
  last_name FFaker::Name.last_name
end

factory :product do
  name Faker::Book.title
  association :author, factory: :author
end

factory :event do
  name FFaker::Lorem.words
  start_time Time.now-3.hours
  end_time Time.now+1.hour

  factory :upcoming_event do
    after(:create) do |event, evaluator|
      # I'm not sure how event and product are associated
      create(:product)
    end
    
  end
end
```

Comment: I was able to do it by
product { create(:product_with_author) }
using curly brace is new syntax in factorybot 2.0

Comment: If its an association, I think the preferred way is to use `association :product, factory: :product`, if it's an association. But like I said, I don't know you're associations

Comment: I didn't define associate specifically. Just define one factory inside factory. And according to document it is considered as inherited association.